# PostgreSQL92Dialect inserting json data in to postgres text column

Tags: json, postgresql, hibernate

We are using hibernate and flyway with postgres database and while inserting json data in to postgres table column of data type text we are seeing value stored in postgres table as "\x7b7d" instead of actual json value where as rest of the columns are getting correct data populated.
We are using org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect.
Same framework and configuration works fine with mysql dialect only issue is with json data in to text data type column. Tried using json and jsonb datatype but getting different framework issues.
In Database url tried using sql.syntax_pgs=true but still no change.

Comment: Does Hibernate really not support anything more up-to-date than 9.2 which has been unsupported for about 5 years now?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.